# Alerts don't show in captcha

Tags: php, html, captcha

I have a Problem in Captcha Alert showing .
When I enter captcha code Incorrcet in Registration Page, The Alerts don't work .

My Captcha Code:

```
<tr>
<td>

  <img src="captcha/captcha_code_file.php?rand=<?php  echo rand(); ?>" id='captchaimg'  style="border:1px solid #CCC;">
  <a href='javascript: refreshCaptcha();'><img src="template/images/refresh.png"/></a>
  <br/><br/>

  <input id="6_letters_code" name="6_letters_code" type="text" style="width:200px;margin-top:-15px;" tabindex="7">
  <br />
  </td>
  </tr>
```

Error Alert code:

```
<?php
if( isset ($_REQUEST['register']) ) {

    if( empty($_SESSION['6_letters_code'] ) || strcasecmp($_SESSION['6_letters_code'], $_POST['6_letters_code']) != 0)
        {
            echo $msg .= '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Please Enter the code correctly !!")</script>';
        }
}?>
```

where I should use this Alert Code ?? after captcha code or end of the my code ??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your IF session and strcasecmp section was messed up a bit. This should work as long as $_REQUEST['register'] and $msg are doing what I imagine you want them to do.

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['register'])) {

    if( 
        (empty($_SESSION['6_letters_code']))
        ||
        (strcasecmp($_SESSION['6_letters_code'], $_POST['6_letters_code']) != 0)
    )
    {
        echo $msg .= '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Please Enter the code correctly !!")</script>';
    }

}

?>
```

As for the alert, perhaps you need to use an auto-displaying JS alert like this (instead of using the "echo $msg .=" line...

```
echo '<body onLoad="javascript:alert(\'Please enter the code correctly!\')">';
```